# WordPress comments form

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have removed the border of form items on my site but I want them on my blogs comment form! 
http://bradburyembroidery.com/houses4cash/blog/hello-world/#comments

I have tried:

```
#commentform input 
{
border:thick;
}
```

but firebug keeps thinking its saying border:thick none;

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The border property is short hand for setting three different properties.

- `border-style`
- `border-width`
- `border-color`

You have set the `border-style` to `none`, set it to something else.

```
#commentform input {
  border: thick black solid;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The order for the shorthand declaration is width, style, color. So it'd be something like:

```
#commentform input
{
border: thick solid #F00;
}
```